# How to restart the process based on condition in jbpm?

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-flow

iam facing issue in jbpm as iam new to the jbpm.
i need to re-start the process or need to jump back to the previous process.
can you any one please suggest how to do it 
my flow is

before saving, based on condition , i need to repocess the flow from getDeclaration.
can any one guide me to do this.

please let me know, if any extra information needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can return to a previous task.

[image: Example of repeating task]

Comment: Hi Mike,
thanks for reply.
one more doubt is how to send data from one task to another task.
i did as below
in task 1:
results.put("LRN", message.getResponse().getDeclaration().getFunctionalReferenceID());

in task 2:
iam reciving it like  String lrn = getParameter(workItem, "LRN");

but iam getting null here.
can you please help me on this